# Inputting string into PostgreSQL results in syntax error at single quote

Tags: python, json, postgresql, syntax-error, psycopg2

I am running through a very large data set with a json object for each row. And after passing through almost 1 billion rows I am suddenly getting an error with my transaction.

I am using Python 3.x and psycopg2 to perform my transactions.

The json object I am trying to write is as follows:

```
{"message": "ConfigManager: Config if valid JSON but doesn't seem to have the correct schema. Adopting new config aborted."}
```

and psycopg2 is reporting the following:

```
syntax error at or near "t"
LINE 3: ...": "ConfigManager: Config if valid JSON but doesn't seem to ...
```

I am aware that the problem is the single quote, however I have no idea of how to escape this problem so that the json object can be passed to my database.

My json column is of type `jsonb` and is named `first_row`

So if I try:

```
INSERT INTO "356002062376054" (first_row) VALUES {"message": "ConfigManager: Config if valid JSON but doesn't seem to have the correct schema. Adopting new config aborted."}
```

I still get an error. And nothing I seem to do will fix this problem. I have tried escaping the `t` with a `\` and changing the double quotes to single qoutes, and removing the curly brackets as well. Nothing works.

I believe it's quite important that I am remembering to do

```
`json.dumps({"message": "ConfigManager: Config if valid JSON but doesn't seem to have the correct schema. Adopting new config aborted."})` in my python code and yet I am getting this problem.
```

Comment: you have to escape `'` and put values with quotes. or use different quotes, like `$not_sgl_quote$` or better prepare statement and then pass value

Comment: Using `$` doesn't seem to work

Comment: Eg: `INSERT INTO "356002062376054" (first_row) VALUES e'{"message": "ConfigManager: Config if valid JSON but doesn\'t seem to have the correct schema. Adopting new config aborted."}'`

Comment: @VaoTsun Doesn't work.. :( `ERROR: syntax error at or near "e'{"message"`or `ERROR: syntax error at or near "'{"message": "ConfigManager: Config if valid JSON but doesn\'"`

Comment: my bad: `INSERT INTO "356002062376054" (first_row) SELECT e'{"message": "ConfigManager: Config if valid JSON but doesn\'t seem to have the correct schema. Adopting new config aborted."}'`

Comment: or: `INSERT INTO "356002062376054" (first_row) values (E'{"message": "ConfigManager: Config if valid JSON but doesn\'t seem to have the correct schema. Adopting new config aborted."}');`

Comment: You should add these two snippets as answers and I will accept them! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dollar sign constraints or C style escape for this. Eg per [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html):

> An escape string constant is specified by writing the letter E (upper
>   or lower case) just before the opening single quote, e.g., E'foo'

So then:

```
INSERT INTO "356002062376054" (first_row) SELECT e'{"message": "ConfigManager: Config if valid JSON but doesn\'t seem to have the correct schema. Adopting new config aborted."}'
```

or

```
INSERT INTO "356002062376054" (first_row) values (E'{"message": "ConfigManager: Config if valid JSON but doesn\'t seem to have the correct schema. Adopting new config aborted."}');
```

should work for you

Answer (score 2):

You have to double a single quote to escape it in SQL.

But the fact that you have this problem means that your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use [parameterized statements](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) and feed the string as parameter when executing the statement. If you do this, the problem will go away.

The `psycopg2` documentation has this dire, but well warranted warning:

> **Warning:** Never, **never, NEVER** use Python string concatenation (`+`) or string parameters interpolation (`%`) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint.

Comment: What is a prepared statement and how exactly should I escape it with double single quotes. Some examples would be preferred :P

Comment: I have added a link to the psycopg2 documentation. That should make it clear.

Comment: Thanks. I am using `"{}".format(some_str)` to do it.

Comment: If you get a problem with single quotes, the solution is not good. If you really don't want to use the best solution, you'll have to turn all `'` to `''` yourself and pray that you don't forget any.